# Elementary proof of Monsky's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

The following curious problem was posed in our problem set for the weekly problem solving session in our institute:

> Prove that a square cannot be decomposed into an odd number of triangles with equal area.

I learnt later that this is called '[Monsky's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem)'. I did not read [Monsky's proof](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Monsky70.pdf), but apparently he used '[Sperner's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma)' and some 2-adic analysis to prove this result.

So,

1. Does relaxing 'equal areas' to 'congruent triangles' admit an elementary proof?
2. It looks like Monsky's statement is true for any polygon with even number of sides. Is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: For 2), this is false if we take quadrilateral with vertices (0,0),(1,0),(1,1/2),(0,1). If you care about regular polygons, this paper, in point (2) in section 6, claims that any partition of regular n-gon, n>4, into equiareal triangles, the number of triangles is divisible by n, so in particular even for n even https://math.berkeley.edu/~moorxu/misc/equiareal.pdf